# How do you switch between windows in IE with SeleniumLibrary in RobotFramework?

Tags: selenium, robotframework

This is the error I am getting when I use the keyword Select Window to switch from my main window to the new window that opens when I click a link:
ERROR: Could not find window with title (Title of the webpage)

I am absolutely positive that the title I am using is correct; I got it straight from the HTML code.

Does anyone have any ideas about what the problem could be?

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed there is a delay in a new window being "visible" to Selenium with Internet Explorer. To work around this, you could create a user keyword using [Get Window Titles](http://rtomac.github.io/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html#Get%20Window%20Titles) and Wait Until Keyword Succeeds to wait for the window to be "visible" to Selenium.

Comment: Delay of how long on average ?

Comment: Somewhere around 1 second.

Comment: OK I have a different issue then. For me it doesn't detect even in a minute